# Continuous action on tensor product

Tags: vector-spaces, group-actions

Let $G$ be a profinite group and $V,W$ be $k$-vector spaces with discrete topology.  Suppose $G$ acts continuously on $V$ and $W$, we extend the action of $G$ to $V \otimes_k W$ by defining on simple tensors as $g.(v \otimes w)=g.v\otimes g.w$. Does $G$ act continuously on $V\otimes_k W$ which is endowed with discrete topology.

Comment: That a profinit group acts continuously on a vector space with discrete topology has a formulation in terms of stabilizers of vectors.

Comment: yeah but does that help the question.

Comment: No, I am randomly mentioning it... :P